# jQuery mobile, works online but not locally

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, local

This problem is driving me crazy. When I reference jQuery  tags to a http adress like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

the application works fine.But when I use this code ( calling  jquery locally )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js" ></script>
```

the application did not work and chrome console gives me this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'event' of undefined       `jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js:7`

I am 100% sure that the files are accessible ( Ctrl + U to show the source and I open the files from my browser, they are there and accessible )
does anyone have the same problem and knows the solution ?

Comment: With your browser tools, go to the network tab, or equivalent.  Do you see the request for jquery.min.js succeeding?  If you have trouble debugging this on mobile devices, try going through a tool like Fiddler as a proxy.

Comment: yes the request succeeds for both css and js files.

Comment: If that is true, and the only difference between your tests is changing that URL, then the file contents or something must be different.  Get a fresh copy from the URL that works.  Also, what is the `Content-Type` response header?  Can you post a URL to your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply the solution is to make a call  to `jquery mobile` AFTER `jquery`,

When using CDN I called jquery before  jquery mobile but locally I inverted the order .

As a consequence  I get that error and that's quite clear  because jquery is not loaded yet !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your local copy of jquery (core) is v1.6.4 or v1.7.1. You are specifically referencing that over the CDN but your markup for the local `<script>` include does not make that clear. jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 is only compatible with these two versions of core.

Comment: it's the same pointed in CDN  just i have renamed it to jquery.min.js simply

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and my code looked like this at first:

```
      <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile.css">
```

But I switched it around to this and it worked:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile.css">
```

Thanks Z!

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow @shon. you can upvote the correct answer or comment it if you want to add something :)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it says I have to have 15 points. So that's why I just wrote the comment. What you said was not immediately obvious to me. I played around with it a bit, and it finally worked. I'm much more visual, so if you posted what you did instead of explaining it I would have got it at first glance. So, that's why I posted it the way I would have understood it. People learn differently you know? I'm a visual learner.

Comment: Ok next time I'll put  that in mind when I answer :)